# $x + y = 7 $and $x^3 - y^3 = 37$, find $xy$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, arithmetic

> $x+y=7$
>   $x^3-y^3 = 37$
>
> Find $xy$

I have tackled this one but I am stuck, when I get to this point:
$$(x-y)((x+2)^2 -xy) = 37$$
I would be glad if you could give me any suggestions.

Comment: Are you looking for integer solutions?

Comment: I need to find the accurate value of "xy". I think I can possibly do it without solving this cubic.

Comment: I think you may have to just realize that  3 and 4 have the desired properties

Comment: Insufficient context : is this an arithmetic problem (find divisors of $37$), an algebra problem (factor a cubic equation) ?

Answer (score 11):

Setting $y=7-x$, we obtain
$$
0=x^3-y^3-37=(2x^2 - 13x + 95)(x - 4).
$$
For integer solutions, the quadratic term has no integer root, so that $x=4$ and $y=3$, hence $xy=12$. Over the real numbers, this is also the unique solution, since $2x^2-13x+95=0$ has two complex, non-real solutions.

Comment: While this seems to be correct I do wonder if there is a way of getting xy without having to fully solve. It seems strange to ask for xy instead of x and y if you need to solve for x and y anyway...

Comment: @Chris Perhaps it was $x+y=7$ and $x^3+y^3=37$; then let $A=diag(x,y)$, so that $tr(A)=7$ and $tr(A^3)=37$. Now find $\det(A)=xy$ by Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: @Chris I, too, suspect that it should be $x^3 + y^3 = 37$.  Then $xy, x+y, x^3+y^3$ are all symmetric polynomials, and every symmetric polynomial, like $xy$, can be written as a sum of the power sum symmetric polynomials, like $x+y$ and $x^3 +y^3$.  In this case, $(x+y)^3 = x^3 + y^3 + 3xy(x+y)$.

Answer (score 1):

$x-y=\pm \sqrt{(x+y)^2-4xy}=\pm \sqrt{49-4xy}$

$x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+y^2+xy)=(x-y)\{(x+y)^2-xy\}$

$\implies \pm \sqrt{49-4xy}(49-xy)=37 $

Hope you can solve this equation to get $xy=12$ as you wanted to solve for $xy$ instead of $x$ and $y$ seperately. Still, I would go with @Dietrich Burde 's solution as you have not stated whether you want natural number solutions or not.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(x^3-y^3)^2$ is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, you can express it as a polynomial in terms of $x+y$ and $xy$ :

$(x^3-y^3)^2 = x^6 - 2x^3y^3 + y^6 = (x+y)^6 - (6x^5y+15x^4y^2+22x^3y^3+15x^2y^4+6xy^5) \\
= (x+y)^6 - 6xy(x+y)^4 + (9x^4y^2+14x^3y^3+9x^2y^4) \\
= (x+y)^6 - 6xy(x+y)^4 + 9(xy)^2(x+y)^2 - 4(xy)^3$

Plugging the values $x+y = 7$ and $x^3-y^3 = 37$ gives you the equation

$4(xy)^3 - 441(xy)^2 +14406(xy)-116280 = 0$

The only rational root of this cubic polynomial is $12$, so this factors as

$(xy-12)(4(xy)^2-393(xy)+9690) = 0$

And now you can check that the second factor doesn't have real roots.

Finally, getting a value for $xy$ (here, $12$) determines the values of $x$ and $y$ completely, because

$x = (x+y)/2 + (x^3-y^3)/(2((x+y)^2-xy))= 7/2 + 37/(2.(7^2-12)) = 4$ and
then $y = (x+y)-x = 7-4 = 3$

Answer (score -1):

$(49-4xy)(49-xy)^2=37^2$
, $37$ is prime. So $49-4xy=1$ then
$$xy=12$$

Comment: Your equation introduces new solutions for $x$, namely the roots of $2x^2 - 15x + 102=0$. How did you come to the equation $(49-4xy)(49-xy)^2-37^2=0$?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde From tatan's answer.

Comment: There is no assumption that $x$ and $y$ are integers, not even necessarily rationals.

Comment: @Batominovski No one say non integer solutions. Dietrich Burde says about integer solution.

Comment: You can find real solutions without assuming anything about the integrality of $xy$.  But I agree, the OP did not make it clear what he wanted.

Comment: @Batominovski But that is ugly solution which we don't want, so I think I gave integer solution.

Comment: Not really ugly, to be honest.  You are merely solving a cubic polynomial equation in $xy$, with one known root $xy=12$.  So, the rest is a quadratic in $xy$, which gives complex roots.  So, you can in principle solve for complex $x$ and $y$ as well.

Comment: Anyway, I am tired of our little game.  I have better things to do.  So long.

Comment: @Batominovski Sorry Although the equation's solutions are yours, my contest sense tells this question's answer is $xy=12$. If you say so, you should stop immediately. I just reply to your messages.